# Show success or error message after form submission (React JS)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, use-state

I'm creating a contact form with Next.Js (React), Typescript and Chakra UI.

I want to show success or error message after form submission depending on the response from backend.

I'm using useState() for this purpose and rendering the message conditionally but this doesn't seem to work,

I'm getting this error

#### **Objects are not valid as a React child. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead**

Here is the part of my code causing error:

```js
export const ContactForm = () => {

     const [status, setStatus] = useState<string>("");
 
     // function to handle form submission
     const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
      
          // some stuff here

          const { error } = await res.json();
          
          // error handling
          if (error) {
              setStatus("error");
              return;
          }

          setStatus("success");
     }

     return (
          // form body here
          
          // here it's failing
          <div>
              {status === "success" ? (
                  <SuccessMessage>{"Message sent successfully"}</SuccessMessage>
              ) : (
                  <ErrorMessage>{"An error occured"}</ErrorMessage>
              )}
          </div>
 
          // submit button
    );
};
```

SuccessMessage and ErrorMessage are custom components

see the error here:

[image]

**Some other methods I've tried that didn't work:**

```js
const [success, setSuccess] = useState<boolean>(false);
const [error, setError] = useState<boolean>(false);

if(error) {
    setError(true);
    return;
}

setSuccess(true);

// conditional render
{ success && ( 
     <SuccessMessage>{"success"}</SuccessMessage>;
)}
{ error && ( 
     <ErrorMessage>{"error"}</ErrorMessage>;
)}
```

This also caused the same error, Objects are not valid as a React child.
If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Is there any way to achieve this, any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Your code has some basic syntax errors, such as `export const ContactForm() = () => {` with the extra brackets. Suggest fixing these and posting your entire component code as it's difficult to diagnose the issue with only part of the picture.

Comment: I've ran a simplified version of your code in a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-https-ryt4d) and it's fine. One thing to note is your default state is "" but your condition says `status === "success" ? (` so the else part that renders the error displays by default.

Comment: @DeanJames that was an oopsy :( It's not in the original code, just wrote here by mistake. And I thought it woulf be better to only show the related part of the code as whole code is too big

Comment: I still think you should post your entire component. Like I said, I've ran your code and it works fine in a sandbox, meaning it's probably due to the code you have omitted.

Comment: How you have defined `SuccessMessage` and `ErrorMessage`?